# iterate through excel slicer options in vba

Tags: excel, pivot, vba

I have a pivot diagram, that has a slicer (and a subslicer) connected  to it. I would like to iterate through all slicer options in vba, one by one, that will return an output (that will show something on the graph, and not just an empty chart area).

How can I do that in VBA?

**EDIT**
I'm trying to iterate through the slicerlist with this code, but the slicerselection never changes:

```
For Each Si In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Afsnit").SlicerItems
    If (Si.HasData) Then
        Si.Selected = True '<<<<<<< this line here does nothing apparently!, the graphs stay the same always, when copied to new documents
        Set WDDoc = WDApp.Documents.Add
            For iCht = 1 To ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
                ' copy chart as a picture
                ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iCht).Chart.CopyPicture _
                    Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture


                WDApp.Selection.Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
                    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False

                WDApp.Selection.MoveEnd wdStory
            WDApp.Selection.Move
            Next

        WDDoc.SaveAs (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileFriendly(Si.Name) & ".doc")
        WDDoc.Close ' close the document

        'get mail for the department
        depmail = Cells(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Enheder").UsedRange.Find(Si.Name).Row, 2).value
        If Not (depmail = "") Then
        X = SendMail(depmail, "ugentlig audit", "Resultater for " & Si.Name, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Si.Name & ".doc")
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: If I get you right, to check if `SlicerItem` is 'greyed out' you need to check `SlicerItem.HasData` property which will return `False` if it is not enabled.

Comment: @KazJaw - exactly right! thank you. Also - do you know if the sliceritems(n) is updated according to other slicers so that SlicerItem(1) will always be a non-greyed out field?

Comment: Yes, `sliceritems(n)` is, as you said, changed according to others but I can find situation when `SlicerItems(1)` is greyed out.

Comment: I tried SlicerItem.Selected = True but that didnt seem to work, is this my local error?

Comment: you have no error and no results? you have proper syntax like `.SlicerItems(1).Selected = True`? you won't have result if `.item.hasdata` returns `false`

Comment: No errors. The documents get created (meaning that We're inside the loop, but the chart doesn't change much to my amazement...

Comment: I didn't realise that you had changed your code. It seems that after you set `.Selected = true` you have to hide all other using `.selected = false` to get only one slice per iteration.

Comment: Moreover, if you try to set `.selected = false` but before that you have the only one item visible all elements would be unhidden after all. Therefore first you need to set `true` and then set others to `false`.

Comment: VBA is such a horrendously buttfugly language, but you sir, are an angel in my moment of despair, thank you so much, you've cured all my evening headaches.

Comment: You're welcome... Added answer with reference to comments to allow you to close question as solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, see comments under the question.